# Как сделать форму поиска по параметрам(фильтрам) из выподающих списков на подобие как на сайте www.booking.com?

Tags: php, select, form

Вопрос состоит в том, что не отправляются данные выбранные в параметре  на сервер в параметр( глобальный массив `$_POST`) . Т.е. из выпадающего списка по номерам `id`(`1,2,3,4,5,6...`), которые генерируются из базы данных ( `<option value="<?=$arr['id']?>"><?=$arr['id']?></option>`).

Я выбираю один из них и он должен параметром подставляться в запрос SQL, для того чтобы в зависимости от переданного `id` можно было выводить на экран соответствующие этому `id` строку из таблицы БД. И в данный момент у меня не получается этого реализовать.

index.php:

```
   include_once ('/connect.php');
   include_once ('/function.php');
   $query = "SELECT id,sh_cont,cont FROM bus";
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   $array = array();
   $i = 0;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $array[$i]['sh_cont'] = $row['sh_cont'];
    $array[$i]['cont'] = $row['cont'];

        $i++;
    }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& isset($_POST['sub'])){
     $id = $_POST['sub'];
      Connect($id);                   
    }
```

Форма:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <select id ="sub" name="sub">
        <?php foreach ($array as $arr):?>
            <option value="<?=$arr['id']?>"><?=$arr['id']?></option>           
        <?php endforeach;?>     
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, что не отправляются данные выбранные в параметре <option> на сервер в параметр( глобальный массив) $_POST. Т.е. из выпадающего  списка по номерам 'id'(1,2,3,4,5,6....), которые генерируются  из базы данных ( <option value="<?=$arr['id']?>"><?=$arr['id']?></option>) я выбираю один из них и он должен параметром подставляться в запрос SQL, для того чтобы в зависимости от переданного 'id' можно было выводить на экран соответствующие этому 'id'  строку из таблицы БД. И в данный момент у меня не получается этого реализовать. Вот и хотел бы у вас попросить работающий пример кода

Comment: Внес в вопрос. Надеюсь на помощь

Answer (score 1):

У вас запрос к бд неправильный, вы не указываете параметры.
Вот небольшой пример, попробуйте переделать под свои нужды.
Форма:

```
<form method="post" action="core.php">
  <select name="select">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Обработчик:

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
        $id = $_POST['select']
        require_once("/database.php"); // Подключение к БД
        $result = $query->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = $id");
        ... // Далее обрабатываем результат 
    }
?>
```

Comment: <?php
      if(isset($_POST['select'])){
           $id = $_POST['select'];
       $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=baza;charset=utf8','root','');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bus` WHERE `id` = $id";
        $result = $pdo->query($sql);
          while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                 echo "<p>".$row['sh_cont']. "|" . $row['cont'];
            }
        }
        ?> Сделал так и теперь поиск по id работает. Спасибо за ответ. Если есть совет по оптимизации кода, то буду признателен

Comment: Да в приниципе, все нормально